# Converting object to array/string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

```
"system_details":
 {
"ucs_version":"00.02",
"ucs_crash_id":"1500000000002A30040000003002B038",
"ucs_static_id":"0x1500000000002A30",
"ucs_variable_id":"0x040000003002B038"
}
```

I have a  javascript object -json, whose value is as above.
1.How can i store each character from json into a array?
         a[0]=", a[1]=v,a[2]=e and so on...........
2.How can i convert the json to a string or key-value pair?
    if a want value of the '**version**' from json, it should output me value       00.02.

Comment: is that a spec?

Answer (score 1):

The code shown is already an object, so `objName.system_details.ucs_version` will return "00.02".

To turn the obj into a string, use `JSON.stringify( objName )`;

To store the characters of a string into an array, you can split it on nothing, so `string.split('')` will just split a string into all its characters.
Eg. `"system_details".split('')` becomes `["s","y","s","t","e","m","_","d","e","t","a","i","l","s"]`

Note that the " around each key and value is not part of the string, so if your array needs to include these, you'll have to add them to the front and the back of the array after splitting the string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

convert your object to string use simple java script function => JSON.stringify
 try this boss 
 JSON.stringify( Your_object);